# Ruby hexdigest sha1 pack('H*') string encoding...

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding, pack, digest

I meet an encoding problem... No errors in the console, but the output is not well encoded.
I **must** use `Digest::SHA1.hexdigest` on a string and then **must** `pack` the result.

The below example should outputs '{´p)ODýGÎ—£Iô8ü:iÀ' but it outputs '{?p)OD?GΗ?I?8?:i?' in the console and '{�p)OD�G^BΗ�I�8^D�:i�' in the log file.

So, my variable called `pack` equals '{?p)OD?GΗ?I?8?:i?' and not '{´p)ODýGÎ—£Iô8ü:iÀ'. That's a big problem... I'm doing it in a Rails task.
Any idea guys?

Thanks

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'digest/sha1'

namespace :my_app do
    namespace :check do
        desc "Description"

        task :weather => :environment do

            hexdigest = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest('29d185d98c984a359e6e6f26a0474269partner=100043982026&code=34154&profile=large&filter=movie&striptags=synopsis%2Csynopsisshort&format=json&sed=20130527')
            pack = [hexdigest].pack("H*")

            puts pack # => {?p)OD?GΗ?I?8?:i?
            puts '{´p)ODýGÎ—£Iô8ü:iÀ' # => {´p)ODýGÎ—£Iô8ü:iÀ

        end
    end
end
```

Comment: How do you know the output should be '{´p)ODýGÎ—£Iô8ü:iÀ'. In what encoding is that supposed to be ?

Comment: I know it because I did the same script in php, rendered in the browser. You can have a look at the 2nd arg of http://bit.ly/bF6nNr
My rail app is in utf8 and my server locals as well.

Comment: I am not sure why you want the result of pack to be a specific *character* sequence? Usually for byte string like a digest there is a requirement to match a specific *byte* sequence, and a need to send or store it by using a well-defined encoding (hex digest in ASCII being one simple but space inefficient scheme). If you do expect a specific character sequence as the output, and then encode to your current web application's output, you will need to specify the encoding to interpret the initial digest bytes as (I'd guess Latin-1), before you convert.

Comment: Rendering in the browser could easily have mangled it, for example if you dumped some raw bytes and the browser interpreted them as utf8

Comment: Note the `hexdigest` and `pack` lines can be combined: `Digest::SHA1.digest( data )` is equivalent in Ruby, and probably slightly faster too.

Comment: I'm sorry Neil. I didn't understand. Any example?
I must encode the string this way because it's for using an api. The provider of the API is waiting for this string encoded this way. But as I get bad encoded special chars, it doesn't match for him when it arrives... Make sense?

Comment: @Gozup: The provider of the API has hopefully explained the character encoding interpretation. However, it is unusual for web APIs to require bytes rendered direct to character sets as they cause exactly this kind of issue. Are you able to share the API instructions - are they public? I don't see a Content-Type specified on your example route - is it supposed to be `application/octet-stream` (this would mean no character encoding applies)?

Comment: No, no documentation. Just the original class that is in PHP and was trying to convert in Ruby... until this problem :-)
https://github.com/gromez/allocine-api/blob/master/PHP/allocine.class.php

Comment: @Gozup, your PHP application appears to be doing a base64 coding of a sha1 digest to generate a variable called `$sig`. Is that what you are trying to replicate in Ruby?

Comment: @Gozup: If that is your application's *real* secret key copied into your question, you now need to change it on the service.

Comment: no don't worry ;-) Let me post what I did

Comment: Seems like an encoding issue. Try `pack.force_encoding('cp1252').encode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this "encoding" issue has turned up due to debugging other parts of a conversion from PHP to Ruby. The target API that will consume a digest of params looks like it will accept a signature variable constructed in Ruby as follows (edit: well this is guess, there may also be relevant differences between Ruby and PHP in URI encoding and base64 defaults):

```
require 'digest/sha1'
require 'base64'
require 'uri'

sig_data = 'edhefhekjfhejk8edfefefefwjw69partne...'
sig = URI.encode( Base64.encode64( Digest::SHA1.digest( sig_data ) ) )
 => "+ZabHg22Wyf7keVGNWTc4sK1ez4=%0A"
```

The exact construction of `sig_data` from the parameters that are being signed is also important. That is generated by the PHP method `http_build_query`, and I do not know what order or escaping that will apply to input params. If your Ruby version gets them in a different order, or escapes differently to PHP, the signature will be wrong (edit: Actually it is possible we are looking here for a signature on the exact query string sent the API - I don't know). It is possibly an issue of that sort that has led you down the rabbit hole of how the signature is constructed?

Comment: Well, I took care of the order of the params. The input string is exactly the same as in PHP version... I've pasted my code below.

Comment: OK, I cannot see what is different between the Ruby and PHP, but that might just be because I don't know enough PHP. I'm reasonably confident that your issue is *not* directly character encoding out of digest or hexdigest/pack or though.

Comment: Thank you Neil, it works now. Answer below. But new problem. If you know how to solve it... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did (my conversion from PHP to Ruby)

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'open-uri'
require 'base64'
require 'digest/sha1'

class Allocine

    $_api_url = 'http://api.allocine.fr/rest/v3'
    $_partner_key
    $_secret_key
    $_user_agent = 'Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.2; Nexus 4 Build/JDQ39E)'

    def initialize (partner_key, secret_key)
        $_partner_key = partner_key
        $_secret_key = secret_key
    end

    def get(id)
        # build the params
        params = {  'partner' => $_partner_key,
                    'code' => id,
                    'profile' => 'large',
                    'filter' => 'movie',
                    'striptags' => 'synopsis,synopsisshort',
                    'format' => 'json' }

        # do the request
        response = _do_request('movie', params)

        return response
    end

    private
    def _do_request(method, params)

        # build the URL
        query_url = $_api_url + '/' + method

        # new algo to build the query
        http_build_query = Rack::Utils.build_query(params)
        sed = DateTime.now.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        sig = URI::encode(Base64.encode64(Digest::SHA1.digest($_secret_key + http_build_query + '&sed=' + sed)))

        return sig
    end
end
```

Then call

```
allocine = Allocine.new(ALLOCINE_PARTNER_KEY, ALLOCINE_SECRET_KEY)
puts allocine.get('any ID')
```

get method return 'e7RwKU9E%2FUcCzpejSfQ4BPw6acA%3D' in PHP and 'cPf6I4ZP0qHQTSVgdKTbSspivzg=%0A' in Ruby...

thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help.
Problem is solved. With the following code I obtain exactly the same string as with PHP:

```
http_build_query = Rack::Utils.build_query(params)
sed = DateTime.now.strftime('%Y%m%d')
sig = CGI::escape(Base64.strict_encode64(Digest::SHA1.digest($_secret_key + http_build_query + '&sed=' + sed)))
```

Now I've another problem for which I opened a [new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789289/php-curllib-and-ruby-net-http-not-returning-same-thing).

thanks you very much.